# Можно ли прилагательное "импозантный" сочетать с неодушевленными сущ.?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Например, какой-нибудь импозантный дворец. Или импозантная статуя. И, если нельзя, то каким словом посоветуете заменить это прилагательное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Импозантный - от "импонировать" - производить положительное впечатление, внушать уважение. Импозантный - способный импонировать. В разное время люди вкладывали в это слово разный смысл (вкусы менялись), но общим оставались следующие значения: внушительный, эффектный, величественный, представительный, способный привлечь внимание. Современное наполнение слова -  представительный, статный, осанистый, внушающий уважение.

В первую очередь всё это относилось к внешности мужчины, но вообще слово «импозантный» можно применять не только к мужчине, но и к неодушевленным предметам, которые каким-либо образом выглядят эффектно или же производят впечатление.

Слово книжное, смысл не всем ясен, в сочетании с неодушевлёнными предметами уместнее употребить презентабельный, величественный, эффектный.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не вижу ошибочного в употреблении прилагательного "импозантный" с неодуш. сущ.
Из Викисловаря: синонимы к слову "импозантный" - впечатляющий, внушительный, представительный.

Comment: Из синонимического ряда ещё не следует сочетаемость слова с неодушевлёнными существительными. В момент заимствования оно употреблялось почти исключительно по поводу внешности персонажей-мужчин вместо слова "представительный", которое тоже имеет ограниченную сочетаемость. Поэтому требуется более серьёзное обоснование.

Answer (score 1):

**ИМПОЗАНТНЫЙ**, [франц. imposant] Книжн. Производящий сильное, поражающее впечатление (своим видом, манерами, обращением и т.п.); **внушительный, представительный.**

Чаще прилагательное "импозантный" относится к одушевленным существительным, но встречаются  и сочетания с неодушевленными предметами, например:

**Импозантный** 6-этажный дом в классическом стиле на углу Eaton Square и Lower Belgrave Street является частью владений герцога Вестминстерского. [Валерий Лебедев. , 2003.11.09]

И Лизавета ... вдруг вспомнила не только седину, орлиный нос и **импозантный пиджак**, но и место Дагаева в большом зале Мариинского дворца [Марианна Баконина. Девять граммов пластита (2000)].

Comment: Современные литераторы многое себе могут позволить. А как обстоит дело с классиками?

Comment: Такие варианты можно отнести к разговорному стилю  по образцу ВНУШИТЕЛЬНЫЙ 1. Производящий солидное впечатление; представительный. В-ая внешность. В. вид. 2. Разг. Значительный по величине, силе; большой, крупный. В-ые цифры, размеры. В. рост. Импозантный вид (не только о человеке):Комиссии  обещали отодвинуть столбы поближе к кремлевской стене, и, таким образом, площадь может принять более импозантный вид. [В. М. Цветаев, И. В. Васнецов. // «Русское слово», 1909]

Comment: Спасибо, мне не попадалось в старых текстах.